# Concurrent inserts mysql - calling same insert stored proc before the first set of inserts is completed

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, scalability, database-performance

I am working on social networking site, which includes the creation of media content and also records the interaction of users with the created content.

**Background of issue - approach used currently**

There is a page called news-feed, which displays the content and activity done with the content by the users they are following on site.

Display order of the content changes with more and more user interactions(eg. if there are more number of comments on a post, its likely to be shown on top of the one with lesser number of comments. However, number of comments is just one of the attributes used to rank the post).

I am using mysql(innodb) database to store the data as follows:

1. activity_master : activities allowed to be part of news feed(post, comment etc)
2. activity_set : for aggregation of activities on the same object
3. activity_feed: details of actual activity

Detailed ER Diagram is at the end of question

**Scenario**

1. A user(with 1000 followers) posts something, which initiates an async call to the procedure to insert the relevant entries(1000 rows for 1000 followers) in above mentioned tables for all followers.
2. Some followers started commenting(activity allowed to be part of news feed) before the above call is completed which initiates another call to the same procedure to insert entries(x total number of their own followers) of this activity for their particular set of followers. (e.g User B commented on this post)
3. All the insert requests(which seems way too many) will have to be processed in queue by innodb engine

**Questions**

1. Is there a better and efficient way to do this? (I definitely think there would be one)
2. How many insert requests can innodb handle in its default configuration?
3. How to avoid deadlock (or resource congestion at database end) in this case
4. Or is there any other type of database best suited in this case

Thanks for showing your interest by reading the description, any sort of help in this regard is much appreciated and let me know if any further details are required, thanks in advance!

[ER Diagram of tables (not reputed enough to embed the image directly :( )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Zje.png)

Comment: There are 3 basic ways: 1. 1 post creates 1000 rows for 1000 follower. 2. 1 post = 1 row, but join with the followees when a user wants to see his timeline. 3. Any mix of 1 and 2. Generally (as broad as your question) there's a lot of documentation about how twitter and facebook do it. So maybe have a look at that to get inspired. They both released special mysql versions to fit it to their needs. And they use other database systems too (so maybe try them out). To find out how many request your system can handle: measure it. For simple queries, it's probably somewhere between 200/s and 10k/s.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for replying. I have read the approach that twitter and facebook  are using and thus, I have decided to go with fan out on write and creating 1000 rows for 1000 users. However, question here asked is different and about the issue that arises if such a call to stored procedure is made within a very less span of time. How to handle this scenario is the issue

Comment: If you have decided to go that route, the rest will depend on your requirements. Benchmark your system, and you will get an estimate of tweets*followers/s you can support. If you e.g. only expect 1 post/s, it should work on every system. You can improve it by getting faster storage and more ram, although that approach is limited (first by your budget, then by principle design issues). At some point, you need to find ways to do load balancing/delayed writes & synchronization/sharding/... MySQL, at least solely, will reach its limits that way (that you can extend by writing your own clone).

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb:  "Don't queue it, just do it".

Inserting 1000 rows is likely to be untenable.  Tomorrow, it will be 10000.

Can't you do the processing on the select side instead of the insert side?

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to read my question and trying to help,
1. As per my knowledge, by default innodb queues all the inserts and not sure how to turn that off (in case its configurable).
2. Well I can do processing on the select side but my main intention is to make reads really fast. I'd definitely be interested in doing fire fighting during inserts. However, if it comes at the cost of data inconsistency then I'll have to look for alternatives like a redis layer over mysql to optimize read speeds from web app

Comment: No, InnoDB performs all queries immediately.  It will, however, delay the updating of non-unique secondary indexes, but this is transparent.

Comment: On the other hand,  unless you are using `tx_isolation` = READ UNCOMMITTED, other transactions do not "see" the inserts until the transaction is `COMMITted`.  This is _not_ 'queuing' or 'delaying'.